# firefox js reference error event is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Below is the JS function which is working fine with IE but not working with firefox.

```
function MyFunction(sender, args) {        
    $(event.srcElement).trigger('RowSelectionChanged', [sender, args]);
    var hdnSelectedRows = $(sender._element.parentElement).find('[id*=hdnSelectedRows]');    
    if (hdnSelectedRows.length > 0) {
        selectedRows = args.getSelectedRows();
        if (selectedRows) {
            if (selectedRows.get_length() > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.get_length(); i++) {
                    hdnSelectedRows.val(args.getSelectedRows().getItemID(i).index + ',');
                }                
            }
            else
                hdnSelectedRows.val('');
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting referenceerror event is not defined

Any help would be highly appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer, the event is defined as a global variable `event`.

In a standard browser, the event must be passed from the event handler callback :

```
myElement.onclick = function(event){
     IWRRC(sender, args, event);
}
function IWRRC(sender, args, event) {
   ... function implementation
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the event handler binding until the call to `IWRRC` ?

Answer (score -2):

Best to say "In Firefox" instead of "in a standard browser". MSIE is also a standard browser.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer and it doesn't address the question.